# how can I override the key and place the new value in it by dict in JSON file?

Tags: python

I want to get an API from somewhere such as a news website but I have an issue which took me a lot of times and I asked here before but I got no clear answer so, I touched the problem now, the overview of the task is I want to create an API but the data always change by the time.

so, my task is so: I need to create a new JSON file to save all data whether it was old or is a new one, the old one will appear in old.html and the new data will appear in news.html therefore, I need to create a dictionary to has the objects but I want the key when it's come in from the request if the same will override the old as Python does with keys but their values will be included in the object key for instance:

```
d = {
    "2020-12-16": {
        "name": "Joe"
    }
}
```

so, the above example is a simple dict but if I reload the page will be getting the new request if there is one and then, the dict will include another named object with the key "2020-12-16" which override the first key so, I want to add the value and Ignore the existing key unless if it has a new data so, in this case, will be added.

also, the last condition is the values of dict will not be repeated so, How can I do that?

sorry for talking long and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
d = {
    "2020-12-16": {
        "name": "Joe"
    }
}

d2 = {
    "2020-12-16": {
        "name2": "Smith"
    }
}

for key, val in d2.items():
    new_dict = d.get(key, {})
    new_dict.update(val)
    d[key] = new_dict
print(d)
```

Will output:

```
{'2020-12-16': {'name': 'Joe', 'name2': 'Smith'}}
```

EDIT:

If you would like each dict to remain independent you need your entries in `d` to be a list of dicts:

```
d = {
    "2020-12-16": [{
        "name": "Joe"
    }]
}

d2 = {
    "2020-12-16": {
        "name": "Smith"
    }
}

for key, val in d2.items():
    entry = d.get(key, [])
    entry.append(val)

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'2020-12-16': [{'name': 'Joe'}, {'name': 'Smith'}]}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I want but I need the key of value like you typed in "name" to be "name", not name2" how can I do that

Comment: @MedoAbdin I don't understand. You want the dictionary to have 2 identical keys? That's not possible. Maybe post an example of the ideal output?

Comment: no, I mean that dictinary have a new dictionary something like that: {'2020-12-16': {'name': 'Joe'}, {'name': 'Smith'}}

Comment: @MedoAbdin I understand, then you need to use a list. I've edited my answer

Comment: I think that is a solution. I'll try it in my API code. thanks a lot @big_bad_bison